# Resolving CoreDNS Loop Error

Tags: kubernetes, resolv.conf

I am trying to resolve a loop error with CoreDNS as part of a 2-node Kubernetes cluster. The issue is thoroughly documented (below), but I am not strong on dns and networking so am having trouble working through it.

Core DNS doco: https://coredns.io/plugins/loop/

Kubernetes manifestation: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1162

**Environment:**

- Home network with no DNS DHCP served through router.
- CIDR: 10.10.0.0/32
- Two Ubuntu 16.x nodes in the cluster (Master is also a Minion)
- /etc/resolv.conf contains:

  > nameserver 127.0.1.1

**Question**

In order to get this working, do I need to set up a nameserver? If so, what should I use? (I have been reading about BIND.) If so, can you please provide some good entry-level info for getting my head around what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075796/coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state/53414041#53414041)? It looks like someone has an issue like yours with the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out that **yes you do need a DNS server for a multi-node cluster**.
The link @Manuel posted is essentially what I was doing and it needs to be done, but they infer you need an external DNS. The instructions for configuring the target DNS server are also incorrect; you cannot make the changes to /etc/resolv.conf the way it describes (or at least I couldn't).

Comment: An update on changing the DNS in resolv.conf...  See this topic where I posted my solution. https://serverfault.com/questions/230456/permanently-change-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server/949063#949063